# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer, but I can't see where it's missing

Tags: javascript

I just started learning javascript, and I want to make an online lcm hcf interactive teaching tool, but I keep getting this error pointed out below, and I can't see where it's missing

```
$("document").ready(function(){

function start() {
    var firstNum = document.getElementById("first-num");
    var secondNum = document.getElementById("second-num");
    var primeList1 = [];
    var primeList2 = [];
    var primes = [];
    var maxPrime = math.max(firstNum, secondNum) / 2 + 1;

    **for (int num = 2; num < maxPrime; num++) {**    <--- this line has the error
        for (int i = 2; num < i; i++)
            if (num % i == 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                primes.add(num);
            };

    };
};
```

Comment: `int num` - What's `int`? Is this java or javascript? Similarly, `i` is declared using `int`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("first-num")` is not int value, it's selector. you should put value on firstNum like `document.getElementById("first-num").value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `int` keyword in JavaScript.

You need to use `var` or `let` to declare and initialize your `num` and `i` variables

```
    for (let num = 2; num < maxPrime; num++) {
        for (let i = 2; num < i; i++)
```

Comment: @Alex you seem to be new here. Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers